# Best way to get new string from existing string

Tags: java, string

I need to re arrange the String and get a new String. Below are the details

```
Current String = 2014-10-15
New String = 20141015
```

I found that we can use split or sub string for this. What is the best way when we consider performance

Comment: Do you have evidence that the simplest possible way (probably just `text.replace("-", "")`) causes significant performance issues in your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Matcher.replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll) method.

> Accroding to the [String doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll)
>   String.split() creates and compiles a new Pattern object. The same is true for the String.replace() methods. This compiling of a pattern each time can cause performance issues in your program if you call the split() or replace() functions in a tight loop.

Below is sample code

```
Pattern replace = Pattern.compile("-");
Matcher matcher = replace.matcher("2014-10-15");
System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll(" "));//out put is:20141015
```

You can use the Pattern object created here multiple times so it will save the time comapred to Strring.replaceAll() method.

Read :[Hidden evils of Java’s String.split() and replace()](http://chrononsystems.com/blog/hidden-evils-of-javas-stringsplit-and-stringr)

Answer (score 1):

Why substring or split here? By looking at your current `String`, `2014-10-15` just replace all `-` with `""`.

You can use [String#replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in `Java`. I don't know what you are talking about performance here since hard to think performance issue in this case.

```
 "2014-10-15".replaceAll("-","")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
String Current= "2014-10-15";
Current=Current.replaceAll("-","");
System.out.println(Current);
```

**Output :**

```
20141015
```

`Note :` The thing is to replace `-` with an empty string.

Fore more on such `string` methods visit [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) link.

Answer (score 1):

[String.replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

```
String Current= "2014-10-15";

System.out.println(Current.replace("-", ""));
```

If you are using any regex means you can user String.replaceAll()

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is much more faster than `replaceAll()`.
In addition if I'm not mistaken, `replaceAll()` uses `Matcher.replaceAll()` in silence, therefore there is not any major differences between them.

```
String text = "123-66-4564-45";
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
int length = text.length();
char[] temp = new char[length];
text.getChars(0, text.length(), temp, 0);
for (char c : temp) {
    if ('-' != c) {
        buffer.append(c);
    }
}
String newText = buffer.toString();
```